# Getting back to schematic entry in the post editor

Tags: support, circuitlab, schematic

I'm practising using the schematic entry in the post editor.
When switching between Firefox 107.0.1 (64-Bit) tabs and windows, the schematic entry disappears time and again, apparently when I click "in the post editor", but outside the schematic entry.
(Sometimes, this is the only way I find to get to continue editing the post body: Trying to leave schematic entry doesn't work, neither from its file menu's *close* entry, nor hitting the x in the upper right corner of the frame.)
Hitting the *Schematic* button in the toolbar again starts an empty one:

How do I get back to what I already entered?

Zooming out to the max doesn't show the plug-in(?).
In Opera 30.0, the tool-bar doesn't show, I don't even get to start schematic entry.

Comment: That isn't it's intended use, the use is I've time only on this site. if you want to use circuitlab then visit thier website https://www.circuitlab.com/

Comment: @VoltageSpike *What* is not the schematic entry's intended use? I'm practising using it to present "circuit ideas" on electronics@SE, not electronics 101 or getting the knack of electronic circuit schematics in general.

Comment: Maybe you just scrolled far off the CircuitLab popup? Have you tried zooming your browser to something like 10% to see if the Circuit Lab frame is anywhere around ?

Comment: @tobalt: I have now, to no avail. Clicking "beside the CIRCUIT**LAB**" reproducibly makes it disappear.

Comment: Maybe add this to your question

Comment: Might help to know what browser, this doesn't happen on my browser. If it's going away, then save the circuit before you switch and then open it back up by posting the answer and then clicking on the edit schematic link